# VIM: Automatically adding menu-items for scripts from a particular directory

Tags: vim, scripting, loops

I have a number of scripts (Ruby as it happens) I run from VIM, by setting up the startup file to contain (for instance):

```
amenu Ruby.script1 :%!ruby C:\ruby_scripts\script1.rb<cr><cr>
amenu Ruby.script2 :%!ruby C:\ruby_scripts\script2.rb<cr><cr>
...
```

What I would like to do, is to have VIM automatically check the `C:\ruby_scripts` directory and assign menu items automatically - can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `glob()` and `exe` with something like this:

```
let dirname = 'c:/ruby_scripts'
for script in split(glob(dirname . '/*.rb'))
    " Get the script name
    let scriptname = fnamemodify(script, ':t:r')
    let scriptfile = fnamemodify(script, ':p')
    " Add the item to the menu
    exe 'amenu Ruby.' . scriptname . ' :%!ruby ' . scriptfile . '<cr><cr>'
endfor
```

For more information, see:

```
:help glob()
:help split()
:help fnamemodify()
:help expand()
:help :exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function! s:AddScript(dir, menuname)
  let files = lh#path#GlobAsList(a:dir, "*.rb")
  for f in files
    let n = fnamemodify(f, ":t:r")
    exe "anoremenu ".a:menuname.".".n." :%!ruby ".f."<cr><cr>"
  endfor
endfunction

call s:AddScript("c:/ruby_scripts", "Ruby")
```

NB: [lh#path#GlobAsList](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/vim-lib/trunk/autoload/lh/path.vim#121) comes from [lh-vim-lib](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhVimLib). With a substitute(), you shall be able to transform globpath() result to the string you'll then need to :execute.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work on my Vim install - I guess due to the lh#path#GlobAsList stuff you mentioned: but still, thankyou very much!

Comment: Yes, this function needs to be installed with its script in the right directory. As it offers some more services you don't seem to need, Al solution is more than enough.